# Multitasking in emu8086

Tags: assembly, operating-system

I have a homework about multitasking in emu8086. I have my kernel  and some programs which runs pretty good in sperate but how do ı make them in multitasking. I have no idea.Teacher said me you can use timer interrupt or a comman counter or double stack but ı have no idea what to do. Can some one help me? any example or nay information about it. because ı am really really newbie at assembly.

Comment: Begin with your own timer ISR. Make it work (say, it would increment a variable in your program and then transfer control to the original timer ISR). Then google up something like "dos timer scheduler assembly".

Comment: Another "fun" way to achieve this is to use 8086 debug flag.

Comment: Your ISR handler should keep multiple copies of the registers. (That's called context). But instead of simply returning to the program/context that was interrupted, the ISR handler should fill the register with another context (and return there). The simplest method is to rely that each process has enough space in their own stack (ss:sp), copy the context there and reverse the procedure at the ISR handler exit.

Comment: Guys ı am really happy for your answer but ı have no idea what to do and what are they you are talking about. ı searched web but there was so comlicated and ı didint understand :S